# $O(n \log n)$ Algorithm for first Train Problem

Tags: algorithms, sorting, search-algorithms, efficiency, divide-and-conquer

On $n$ parallel rails there are $n$ trains with constant speeds $v_1, ..., v_n$. At time $0$ the trains are at positions $k_1, ..., k_n$. Find an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm that determines which trains are in the lead at least once.

My current approach is to create a 2-dimensional coordinate system, time as x-axis and position as y-axis both only for positive values. Then i add a linear equation for each train: $y = v_i \cdot x + k_i$.

Then my first idea was to take the train with the furthes starting position since it is in the leading position at time 0. Then calculate the first intersection with another train $v_j$, then from this point calculate the first intersection of $v_j$ with another train and so on. But this leads to a runtime of $O(n^2)$ which is not good enough.

I talked to some colleagues and we discussed the option of a divide-and-conquer approach but couldn´t find a solution.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this platform i am not familiar with how to ask questions here, i try to give a bit more information. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: On a time-space diagram, the trains each describe a straight line. What you are after is the upper envelope of these lines. This problem seems closely related to that of the construction of a convex-hull.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**

Your approach is good. The algorithm type you are looking for is called a "scan line" algorithm. The idea is that you move from left to right on your 2d model and at each intersection (an "event") update data structures.

**Hint 2:**

In your case the you maintain a ordered binary search tree of the trains (sorted by which train is currently ahead). You also maintain a priority queue of "events".

**Hint 3:**

Each event is struct which contains at what time it occurs and  which two trains are gonna change position in the "leader board" (the BST).
Since positions only change at an event, you use these to note which trains were ahead once. Since trains can only change places when they are next to each other you can generate events quite easily. Basically in the beginning you create an event for each pair of neighboring trains, and after every event you create  new events for the trains that switched places and their new neighbors (in the leaderboard).
Keep in mind that getting the lower and upper neighbors in a BST is $O(log(n))$ and extracting and placing elements in a priority queue is $O(log(n))$ as well.

This is very similar to the [Bentley-Ottmann-Algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm)